EventGrid Trigger on Authenticated Azure Function App
I have an Azure Function App with several different functions. Some of which with an HTTP trigger and one with an Event Grid Trigger.
I want to force authentication on the HTTP triggers but when I enable that, my Event Grid can't trigger the function that should be triggered. This is the error I get in Log Analytics:
outcome=Unauthorized
latencyInMs=1600
id=0f82d947-028f-4fda-8f02-ff2b5b91997d
outputEventSystemId=61e3220c-ca44-42d3-a747-42ed44104871
state=FilteredFailingDelivery
deliveryTime=12/6/2024 3:13:39 PM
deliveryCount=0
probationCount=1
deliverySchema=EventGridEvent
trackedSystemTopicState=CreatedExplicitlyByUser
eventSubscriptionDeliverySchema=EventGridEvent
outputEventFields=InputEvent| EventSubscriptionId| DeliveryTime| State| Id| ProbationCount| LastHttpStatusCode| LastDeliveryOutcome| DeliverySchema| LastDeliveryAttemptTime| SystemId| UseMappedResourceArmIdForBilling| TrackedSystemTopicState
outputEventFieldCount=12
dedicatedQueueDeliveryQueueId=
requestExpiration=1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
delivered=False id=40706be1-9f96-4b99-9fda-7a940e8cf1b7
inputEventSystemId=d11146fa-4136-4fad-9388-097739fa3b0c publishTime=12/6/2024 3:13:38 PM
eventTime=12/6/2024 3:13:37 PM
eventType=Microsoft.AppConfiguration.KeyValueModified
deliveryTime=1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
filteringState=FilteringPending
inputSchema=EventGridEvent
publisher=MICROSOFT-APPCONFIGURATION-CONFIGURATIONSTORES.WESTEUROPE-1.EVENTGRID.AZURE.NET
size=682
subject=https://appconfiguration.azconfig.io/kv/qwerty?label=apmgroup-Group1&api-version=2023-10-01
inputEventFields=Id| PublishTime| SerializedBody| EventType| Topic| Subject| FilteringHashCode| SystemId| Publisher| FilteringTopic| TopicCategory| DataVersion| MetadataVersion| InputSchema| EventTime| FilteringPolicy
inputEventFieldCount=16
type=AzureFunction
subType=NotApplicable
supportsBatching=False
aadIntegration=False
managedIdentityType=None
armId=/subscriptions/<subid>/resourceGroups/<rgname>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<function app name>/functions/<function name>
deliveryResponse=Unauthorized
errorCode=Unauthorized
HttpRequestMessage: httpVersion=1.1
HttpResponseMessage: HttpVersion=1.1
StatusCode=Unauthorized(Unauthorized)
StatusDescription=Unauthorized
IsRedirected=False
RedirectUrl=

Is there a way to exclude the Event Grid from having to authorize? Or is there another possible solution?

As per the  Eventgrid documentation, Azure functions is not a supported handler for the AzureAD or MSI authentication methods. For Azure AD and MSI, only webhooks are supported. So I would suggest you to create a http trigger function and expose it as a webhook endpoint. This webhook can be integrated with Azure AD so that the events can be authenticated

@hofa, you can grant permission to the event grid identity permission to the function app or you could allow unauthenticated requests to your function app and check auth in code for the endpoints that required authentication.

As Sampath said, I have to set up webhooks to get this to work. I needed a whole day to get this to work with the authentication but eventually, the key settings were

The app registration being used in the EventGrid subscription (in the Event Subscription settings: Additional Features > Microsoft Entra Auth) needs to be a different app registration than the one used for authentication in the Azure Function App settings
Microsoft Identity provider in the Function App Authentication Settings should be configured with:

Allowed token audiences = App Id used in the EventGrid Subscription (see first bullet point)
Client application requirement = Allow requests from specific client applications

App Id for the identity provider itself (to be found on the same page)
4962773b-9cdb-44cf-a8bf-237846a00ab7 (= Microsoft.EventGrid Enterprise Application App Id, don't change this - this was missing from the Microsoft example scripts to be found here)





edit: should have read this article better. It tells you to go find the Microsoft.EventGrid Enterprise Application App Id...
